# Kendo Web UI Performance

Tags: kendo-ui

I using Kendo Web UI datepicker and NumericTextBox with the web application and loading of the context is very slow and it takes about 3 secs. After further investigation and found the ajax call to the server gets the data in 174ms and rest of the time is spent at client which was alarming to me. Looking in details using console.time found the 80% of the time taken by kendo web UI.

The html dom is loaded using jquery $.get Ajax method. OnSuccess the document's div is loaded with html data and run kendo NumericTextBox and DatePicker.

```
$(".currency").kendoNumericTextBox({ format: "c", decimals: 3, spinners: false });
$(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
```

The above 2 lines of code takes around 2194 ms.

Is there a way of improving the speed for the above lines?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems too much according my experience. How many records are you transferring? Could you post a full example of what you are doing?

Comment: I am transferring about 74 records only.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense... Let me put one example in place and you will see that it takes much less...

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mcy7N/. Click on _Transform_ and  and let me know how long does it take. Is this (basically) what you do?

Comment: i have checked your example and it takes 400ms when i click on transform button, which sounds ok but mine takes up to 2230ms. Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/jf2s9/. I am using console.time for log the time takes for the execution so you should be able to see logs on console windows as #kendoNumericTextBox: 1024.000ms and #kendoDatePicker: 1206.000ms

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not initializing KendoDatePicker and KendoNumericTextBox but doing it inside a form.

If you remove the `<form>` from your JSFiddle (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jf2s9/1/) you will see that it is pretty fast.

Knowing this and assuming that you really need that form, what you might do is replace the `form` by a `div` element and one Kendo initialization is done, wrap the new `div` by your `form` definition.

Example:

Replace this:

```html
<div class="eCheckList-section">
    <div class="dividends eCheckList-Body">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input id="FileId" name="FileId" type="hidden" value="68f323b2-128e-4f9d-91bc-c0fcfe0f7615" />
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ClientId must be a number." data-val-required="The ClientId field is required." id="ClientId" name="ClientId" type="hidden" value="28608" />
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

by this:

```html
<div class="eCheckList-section">
    <div class="dividends eCheckList-Body">
        <div id="form">
            <input id="FileId" name="FileId" type="hidden" value="68f323b2-128e-4f9d-91bc-c0fcfe0f7615" />
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ClientId must be a number." data-val-required="The ClientId field is required." id="ClientId" name="ClientId" type="hidden" value="28608" />
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, the code for initializing Kendo widgets and *creating* the `form`:

```javascript
console.time("#kendoNumericTextBox");
$(".currency").kendoNumericTextBox({ 
    format: "c", 
    decimals: 3, 
    spinners: false
});
console.timeEnd("#kendoNumericTextBox");

console.time("#kendoDatePicker")
$(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
console.timeEnd("#kendoDatePicker");

console.time("#buildForm");
$("#form").wrap("<form action='' method='post'></form>");
console.timeEnd("#buildForm")
```

Your JSFiddle modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jf2s9/3/

Comment: Hi, This was my problem, could you please explain why?

Comment: For anyone else who is still wondering why. Telerik explained it here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/serious-performance-issue-when-initializing-kendo-web-ui-widgets-inside-a-form